# Keep Drupal updated

Tags: drupal, cron, drush

I am trying to keep a couple of Drupal sites updated and I tired of the whole process. I recently find out about Drush and I was wondering if there is a module or a CRON command I can setup to keep the sites updated for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your crontab to get Drush to update your Drupal copy everyday at 12:01 PM:

```
1 12 * * * drush -y up
```

Comment: Thank you Omar. Will that also perform a site backup in case of a update? Also if there is nothing to update what happen?

Comment: Drush takes automatic backups for your code before the update and nothing will happen if there are no updates pending, drush will simply quit.

Answer (score 3):

I can see why you would want to automatically update your site, but doing so with or without drush is not advisable.

Not all module updates are backwards compatible (eg. ctools) and not all combinations of modules work together - drush does not take this into account - it just updates regardless. Add to this the possibility that the developer of a module accidentally adds another error as he or she fixed an exiting one.

Therefore you really need to test your site everytime you update a module to verify that everything works as intended. The convenience of autoupdates via cron doesn't really outweigh the troubles if clients call you up because the site crashed.